# Rails with Existing Database Model has no columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

Im developing a new rails app with an existing SQL SERVER 2008 database.

I read somewhere that rails 4.2 doesn't support SQL SERVER 2008 so I downgraded to 4.1 (if this matters)

I create a model using rails g model command then deleted the migration file

```
class IpProject < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'IP_Projects'
    self.primary_key = "ProjectID"
end
```

when I try to query

```
IpProject.all.count
```

it shows the number of rows

but I can't display the output 
I then tried to display the columns by

```
IpProject.column_names
```

but it's an empty []

Could someone tell me what I'm missing here?

By the way I'm using tiny_tds and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

Comment: what it is given when `result = client.execute("USE [tinytdstest]")
result.fields`

Comment: it shows [] when i tried it